# Доступ к элементам формы через внешние методы

Tags: python, gui, pyqt4

Друзья, как через сторонний метод передавать данные на форму?
Так понимаю, здесь стоит рыть в сторону сигналов, но всё никак не разберусь, как и зачем их нужно подключать.
На данном примере хотелось бы устанавливать надпись на кнопку из QLineEdit, но чтобы всё это шло через Cycle, а не через методы MyWindow.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from time import sleep
import sys

global i; i=0

def Cycle():
    while(True):
        i+=1
        print(i)
        sleep(1)

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
    def run(self):
        Cycle()

class MyWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button=QtGui.QPushButton("START")
        self.label=QtGui.QLabel("")
        self.txtName = QtGui.QLineEdit('', self)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.vbox=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.txtName)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.connect(self.button,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.on_clicked)
        self.mythread=MyThread()
    def setTextOnButton(self):
        self.button.setText(str(i))
    def on_clicked(self):
        self.setTextOnButton()
        self.mythread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=MyWindow()
    window.resize(250, 50)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ND7, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @Захар Скороходов, в итоге мой код всё-таки оказался правильным, поток объявляется только один раз, просто не знал, как обращаться к виджетам, создавать ли экземпляр MyWindow.

    def Cycle():
        while(True):
            window.button.setText(window.txtName.text())

Answer (score 1):

Как идея:

```
def cycle(window):
    while(True):
        i+=1
        window.button.setText(str(i))
        sleep(1)

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
    def run(self, window):
        Cycle(window)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window=MyWindow()
    window.resize(250, 50)
    window.show()
    # ###
    mythread=MyThread()
    mythread.run()
    # ###
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Надо только вспомнить, где именно запускать mythread.run() - до или после sys.exit(app.exec_()).